# Is it possible to use multi-threading with the igraph R library?

Tags: r, multithreading, igraph

Is it possible to use multithreading with the igraph library in R ? Because I tried to run clusterisation on my graph_object on a single thread but this clusterisation is always stopped

Comment: Does R give you an error message?

Comment: Yes, I got "Process stopped" and it closes the R window.